# how to keep ordered rows in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote the following script to retrieve the gene count for each contains. It works well but the order of the `ID list` that I use as an input is not conserved in the output.
I would need to conserve the same order as my input contigs list is ordered depending on their level of expression
Can anyone help me?
Thanks for your help.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np
gene_list = {}
for line in open('idlist.txt'):
    columns = line.strip().split()
    gene = columns[0]
    rien = columns[1]
    gene_list[gene] = rien
gene_count = defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(6, dtype=int))
out_file= open('out.txt','w')

esem_file = open('Aquilonia.txt')
esem_file.readline()
for line in esem_file:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    exon = fields[0]
    numbers = [float(field) for field in fields[1:]]
    if exon in gene_list.keys():
         gene = gene_list[exon]
         gene_count[gene] += numbers
         print >> out_file, gene, gene_count[gene]

input file:
comp54678_c0_seq3
comp56871_c2_seq8
comp56466_c0_seq5
comp57004_c0_seq1
comp54990_c0_seq11
...
output file comes back in numerical order:
comp100235_c0_seq1 [22 13 15  6 15 16]
comp101274_c0_seq1 [55  2 27 26  6  6]
comp101915_c0_seq1 [20  2 34 12  8  7]
comp101956_c0_seq1 [13 21 11 17 17 28]
comp101964_c0_seq1 [30 73 45 36  0  1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `collections.OrderedDict()`; it preserves entries in input order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('idlist.txt') as idlist:
    gene_list = OrderedDict(line.split(None, 1) for line in idlist)
```

The above code reads your `gene_list` ordered dictionary using one line.

However, it looks as if you generate the output file purely based on the order of the input file lines:

```
for line in esem_file:
    # ...
    if exon in gene_list:  # no need to call `.keys()` here
        gene = gene_list[exon]
        gene_count[gene] += numbers
        print >> out_file, gene, gene_count[gene]
```

Rework your code to first collect the counts, then use a separate loop to write out your data:

```
with open('Aquilonia.txt') as esem_file:
    next(esem_file, None)  # skip first line
    for line in esem_file:
        fields = line.split()
        exon = fields[0]
        numbers = [float(field) for field in fields[1:]]
        if exon in gene_list:
             gene_count[gene_list[exon]] += numbers

with open('out.txt','w') as out_file:
    for gene in gene_list:
        print >> out_file, gene, gene_count[gene]
```

Comment: @freak: That semicolon is part of the sentence, **not** part of the object name.

Comment: @ Martijn Thanks very much for your fast reply, I tried to implemente this solution but it is still not working.

Why using for line in idlist? line is not defined before

Comment: It is a generator expression; `line.split(None, 1)` is taken from the loop that follows `for line in idlist`. It doesn't 'work' because your output file order is determined wholly by your input file order (`esem_file`).

Comment: okay so if I cannot change the order of my esem_file, can I determine the order of the output with the idlist?

Comment: If you want items to appear in the order of `idlist`, you'd need to rework your code to first collect all the data, then loop over `gene_list` to determine the output order. `gene_list` retains the order of the `idlist` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot I am going to try that!